# How does Gain-switching produce intensity spikes?

Tags: thermodynamics, laser, laser-interaction, laser-cavity

- Gain switching is described in my lecture notes as "we simply control  how long we supply 
  energy to the laser for, and thus how long the laser remains above threshold for. As the laser only emits when the  gain     >  loss,    so a    pulse   of 
  light   may be  formed." How does this create a pulse? To me this sounds akin to holding my hand over a flashlight and then quickly removing and putting my hand back to cover it. This doesn't seem like when I remove my hand *more* light will come out, the same but for a different amount of time. Not more power or anything we think of with pulsed lasers.
- According to this diagram, Pulse-Repetition Frequency is defined as 1/Tinterval (Am I write in assuming an amount of displacement t on this graph is referred to as time bandwidth? If not, what is it?) Where is the intuition behind this?
  [image]
- One more question. Thanks very much for bearing with me. Am I right in assuming this graph has to do with the varied amounts of intensities with the necessary gain, when going through both resonators and through the gain medium, produce net output gain? What do those arrows represent, (lasing modes.. huh?) and what explains the general curved figure of the graph?
  [image]

Comment: Please separate your different questions into individual posts.